# Kotlin NumberFormatException

Tags: kotlin

Why `"b23c77126dd924bf".toLong(16)` produces `java.lang.NumberFormatException` ??

As of [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-long/index.html), Long "Represents a 64-bit **signed** integer"

And `0xb23c77126dd924bf` fits in 64 bits, it is decimal `-5603472915319675713`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that if you don't explicitly prepend the `-` sign before a Kotlin literal, then the literal is always assumed to represent a positive number. So here 0xB23C77126DD924BF is not interpreted according to its two's-complement representation, which would give you -5603472915319675713 if you assume it's a 64 signed integer. It is interpreted as 12843271158389875903, which is outside of Long supported range.

This is the same question as [Java Integer.MAX_VALUE vs Kotlin Int.MAX_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462793/java-integer-max-value-vs-kotlin-int-max-value), but here it's related to Long instead of Int.

Answer (score 0):

Its working   .Use BigInteger

```
        val numb = "b23c77126dd924bf"
        val res = BigInteger(numb, 16)
        println(res)     //12843271158389875903
        println(res.toLong()) //-5603472915319675713
```