# Java Integer.MAX_VALUE vs Kotlin Int.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, kotlin

I noticed, one interesting thing.
Java's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7fffffff` (2147483647)
Kotlin's `Int.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`
but if you write
in Java:
`int value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
//everything is fine (but printed value is '-1')`
in Kotlin:
`val value: Int = 0xFFFFFFFF //You get exception
The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Int`

Interesting right? So you're able to do something like `new java.awt.Color(0xFFFFFFFF, true)` in Java but **not** in Kotlin.

`Color` class works with that int on "binary" level, so everything works fine for both platforms with all constructors (`Color(int rgba)` or `Color(int r, int g, int b, int a)`).
Only workaround which I found for kotlin is `java.awt.Color(0xFFFFFFFF.toInt(), true)`.

Any idea why is it like this in Kotlin?

Comment: I think Java automatically widens the number, `Int` to `Long`. --- See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html --- and also see http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/SCJP/0080__Type-Casting/WideningandNarrowconversions.htm --- In Kotlin you have to do it explicitly, no language automatism to save you from having chosen a too narrow type.

Comment: @Mörre `0xFFFFFFFF` is a valid two's complement representation of `-1` as an `int`. The difference between the two languages is that Kotlin literals don't seem to accept two's complement notation; the literal `0x80000000` is an error (in Java, it's `Integer.MIN_VALUE`). In other words, you must use a unary `-` operator to represent negative literals. Although I can't find any specific mention of this in the spec of either language.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Please look at `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: What about it? I don't see anything about it that contradicts my comment.

Comment: @bcsb1001 I don't see how yours contradicts mine. See comments below, Paul's answer.

Comment: @Mörre Because there is no widening conversion happening, which you seem to suggest there is.

Comment: @bcsb1001 See below, comments, Paul's answer.

Comment: @Mörre There's no widening in applying an int value to an int field.

Comment: See https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/when-does-bit-fiddling-come-to-kotlin/2249  - *The current master plan is (...) have large hex constants have unsigned types (i.e. 0xFFFFFFFF is not a negative Int, but an unsigned Int, i.e. UInt)*.  It's coming from wanting to protect you from unexpected overflow nuances, but 99.9% of the time you use hex you probably care about the bits, not the actual value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this problem should be solved by **Kotlin 1.3** and `UInt`
See more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#unsigned-integers

Answer (score 6):

This is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175798/write-a-hexadecimal-integer-literal-equal-to-int-min-value-in-kotlin):

> In Kotlin you need to prepend the `-` sign to denote negative Int which is not true in Java.

So it seems that Java will interpret hex literals as [signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), whereas Kotlin will treat them as unsigned.

The negation would have to be done manually.

Small aside: JetBrains' Kotlin converter actually converts

```
int a = 0xffffffff;
```

to

```
var a = -0x1
```

but this may just be it realizing exactly what you have noticed.

---

[The part of the spec for hexadecimal literals](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#hexadecimal-integer-literals) doesn't mention this at all, however.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is in the [reference docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions):

> Due to different representations, smaller types are not subtypes of
>   bigger ones. If they were, we would have troubles of the following
>   sort:
>
> ```
> // Hypothetical code, does not actually compile:
> val a: Int? = 1 // A boxed Int (java.lang.Integer)
> val b: Long? = a // implicit conversion yields a boxed Long (java.lang.Long)
> print(a == b) // Surprise! This prints "false" as Long's equals()
>               // check for other part to be Long as well
> ```
>
> So not only identity, but even equality would have been lost silently
>   all over the place.
>
> As a consequence, smaller types are NOT implicitly converted to bigger
>   types. This means that we cannot assign a value of type Byte to an Int
>   variable without an explicit conversion.

Comment: This isn't the question. In Java, `0xFFFFFFFF` would still be an `int`. Additionally `int` is definitely not larger than `long`

Comment: Yes, I am sure. `0xFFFFFFFF` when interpreted as signed is clearly `-1` (and is 32 bits).

Comment: Does this comment from that linked answer help? "You can write int i = (int)Long.MAX_VALUE; and it will be -1. I agree that it is weird, because _compiler complains on int i = 4294967295_; but doesn't complain on int i = 0xffffffff;. I think, basically this is because 0x... is treated as a bit sequence and then is casted to the desired type."

Comment: But fair call, this answer doesn't cover the question. I'll leave it to accrue downvotes :)

Comment: That comment is actually exactly my point. `0xFFFFFFFF` _is_ an `int`. Same as `0b11111111111111111111111111111111`, when treated as a 32 bit integer the high bit is `1` and due to representation of signed integers this has a value of `-1`. When treated as any wider type (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFFL`) the value is of course positive, though ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/319206/7366707))